# UWP Win2D: how to check if a Path intersects a Rectangle

Tags: c#, uwp, geometry, win2d

I need a super-fast way to check if a given `Path` intersects a given `Rectangle`.

For this purpose, I came out with this method, which "crops" the `Path` on the given rectangle and checks if anything has been painted in such area.

```
    public static readonly CanvasDevice CanvasDev = CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice();
    private static readonly CanvasRenderTarget s_offScreen = new CanvasRenderTarget(CanvasDev, 10, 10, 96);
    public static bool IsPathDrawnInsideRect(this CanvasGeometry geom, Vector2 offset, byte alphaThreshold)
    {
        if (geom == null)
            return false;

        using (CanvasDrawingSession ds = s_offScreen.CreateDrawingSession())
        {
            // do not forget clear buffer
            ds.Clear(Colors.Transparent);

            ds.DrawGeometry(geom, offset, Colors.Black);
        }

        byte[] bytes = s_offScreen.GetPixelBytes();
        return bytes.Any(c => c > alphaThreshold);
    }
```

The method works, and it is pretty accurate (at least, is accurate enough for my purpose), but unfortunately the statement `s_offScreen.GetPixelBytes();` takes sometimes up to 10ms to execute, and I need the full method to stay within 1ms.

Is there a faster way to check if the given `CanvasRenderTarget` contains any pixel with an ALPHA channel higher than a specified threshold?

Or alternatively, how can I configure the `CanvasRenderTarget` (in terms of `DirectXPixelFormat` and `CanvasAlphaMode`) to get the max performance for this scenario?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

In UWP, there is [a method that checks if two geometries intersect](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/M_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_Geometry_CanvasGeometry_CompareWith.htm).

```
if (CanvasGeometry.CreateRectangle(CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice(), rectangle).CompareWith(your_geometry) == CanvasGeometryRelation.Overlap)
{
    //geometries intersect
}
```

Note that the method returns one of four values. In addition to Overlap they can be Disjoint, but also your geometry can be contained in the rectangle or the rectangle can contain your geometry.